# Preserve scope values while moving template in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I have two collections binded to ui that populate through `ng-repeat`

In that I have included `ng-include="template.html"`

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items1">
    <ng-include src="item.template"></ng-include>
   </div>
</div>

<div>
   <div ng-repeat="item in items2">
     <ng-include src="item.template"></ng-include>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my templates are like below

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
    <div ng-controller="controller1"> <input ng-model="a"/></div>
</script>
```

And in my controller is like below

```
myApp.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.items1 = [];
    $scope.items2 = [];

    var item1 = {
        name: "1",
        template: "template1.html"
    };
    var item2 = {
        name: "2",
        template: "template2.html"
    };
    var item3 = {
        name: "3",
        template: "template3.html"
    };

    $scope.items1.push(item1);
    $scope.items1.push(item2);
    $scope.items1.push(item3);

    $scope.reAddItem = function () {
        $scope.items2.push($scope.items1.pop());
    }
});
```

and another controller which is referenced in template is like below

```
myApp.controller("controller1", function ($scope) {
    console.log("Initialized");
    $scope.a = 'hello';
});
```

now i want to preserve the controller scope variables when I move items from one collection to another collection, (if i have inputted some value in input box that scope value should retain same when moving around collection), but angular always creates a new scope and destroy previous scope values when templates are re-added in ng-repeat.

But I dont want that and retain the same template when moving around collections, so how can I do that?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rushi216/8988z/1/)

In above fiddle i want same scope variable if I change something in input box and move it into another collection

Comment: Since the `item`s are being moved, you should probably keep the variable `a` in each item, instead of in the scope.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but what I want basically is retaining the scope variables after moving the template, In this example it is only one variable, but in my real application there are several scope variable which I need to be retained

Comment: Wrap all the extra variables under a property of item. At least that is what I would do. Besides, this data is probably going to be stored somewhere anyway. Why not storing it in the item itself? There can be other complicated solutions, but I see no reason.

Answer (score 0):

As someone has commented something like [this might](http://jsfiddle.net/8988z/5/) work

```
var item1 = {
    name: "1",
    hoo:'asdfasdf',
    template: "template1.html"
};
var item2 = {
    name: "2",
    hoo:'adddddddsdfasdf',
    template: "template2.html"
};
var item3 = {
    name: "3",
    hoo:'asdfasdffffffffffff',
    template: "template3.html"
};
```

and

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
   <div ng-controller="controller2"> <input ng-model="item.hoo"/></div>
</script>
```